# Error: Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matAutocomplete" (""auto" [formControl] ="..."

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing

I am writing unit test to check if component is getting created successfully. I see the following error
 Error: Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matAutocomplete" (""auto"  [formControl

This is my template.html which contains auto-complete directive

```
<mat-form-field >
  <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto"  [formControl]="customerFilterControl">
  <mat-autocomplete panelWidth ="450px" #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith] = "displayFn" style="width:750px;">
     <mat-option  *ngFor="let customer of filteredOptions | async" [value] ="customer.AccountID + '('+ customer.AccountName + ')'" (click)="onCustomerChange(customer)">
      {{customer.AccountID}} ({{customer.AccountName}})
     </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

This is the unit test spec.file, I have tried the following things,

```
import { ActualComponent } from './ActualComponent';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,Directive } from '@angular/core'; 

@Directive({
  selector:'<matAutocomplete>',
})
export class matAutocomplete{}

 beforeEach(()=>{
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       imports:[....],
      declarations:[...matAutocomplete],(1)
       ...
     schemas:[NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA] //this didn't fix (2)
})

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  })
```

I expected test to pass for  (1) defining directive "matAutocomplete" and declaring in spec file (2) decalring schemas in testbed config But still test is not passing! Does anyone have suggestion for me?

Comment: `declarations:[...matAutocomplete],(1)` hope that is in RL `declarations: [matAutocomplete]`... btw I would use CamelCase class names, starting with a capital letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector `<matAutocomplete>` will not work. Try to use `[matAutoComplete]` and add a `@Input() matAutocomplete` to the class. Next step would be to add `exportAs` to the directive decorator:

```js
@Directive({
  selector:'[matAutocomplete]',
  exportAs: 'matAutocomplete'
})
export class matAutocomplete {
   @Input() matAutocomplete: any;
}
```

**UPDATE**
May be it would be better to test this with the Angular Material Modules imported. Otherwise the test does not really test anything relevant.

Can you try the following:

1)

```js
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';


...
// inside beforeEach:
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports:[ReactiveFormsModule, 
           MatAutocompleteModule, MatInputModule, 
           MatSelectModule, MatFormFieldModule],
  declarations:[AppComponent],  // add your component instead of AppComponent

  // schemas:[NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA] 
});
```

2) Remove the custom `matAutocomplete` directive.

Comment: Hi ChrisY, looks logically perfect to me  but this is what I see when I run the test      Error: Template parse errors:
        There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matAutocomplete" (""auto"  [formControl]="customerFilterControl">
                      <mat-autocomplete panelWidth ="450px" [ERROR ->]#auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith] = "displayFn" style="width:750px;">

Comment: I read your earlier comment, good to follow conventions.Inside testbed under declaration I defined the class   declarations:[..,MatAutoComplete],

Comment: @Directive({
  selector:'[matAutocomplete]',
  exportAs: 'matAutocomplete'
})
export class MatAutoComplete {
   @Input() matAutocomplete: any;
}